# GXP Ortho Polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I am creating an orthomosaic using SocetGXP. When I try to process my mosaic I get an error GXP RPF.exe has failed. I have narrowed this down to a problem in my seamlines of either extremely small polygons where the polygon boundaries have become snapped into wrapped almost figure 8 pattern or multiple vertices of a single polygon become snapped creating a stack of vertices.

Is there a tool in ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap) that can identify wrapped polygons or stacked vertices?

Comment: To check for/fix those kinds of errors, you can use [check geometry](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/check-geometry.htm)
 or [repair geometry](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm)